# How to call controller method from drag and drop sortable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jquery sortable to allow me to drag and drop li elements within its own ordered list and other's ordered list. It's working great. I'm now wondering how can I keep track of this and pass this info into a method into my controller?

html:

```
<ul id="grpId">
        @foreach (var item in Model.GeneratedGroups)
        {                  
            <li id="draggable">Group @Html.DisplayName(item.GroupNumber.ToString())<br />
                <ol class="connectedSortable" >
                    @foreach (var student in item.GroupMembers)
                    {
                        <li draggable="true" ><span>@String.Format("{0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName)</span></li>
                    }
                </ol>

            </li>

        }
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#draggable ol").sortable({ connectWith: ".connectedSortable" });
   $("#draggable ol").disableSelection();
</script>
```

How can I now call a @Url.Action or implement ajax somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#draggable ol").sortable({
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        //Your ajax call here
    }
});
```